# Pandas Multiindex Series Within Group Sort

Tags: pandas

I have an pandas multi index series

```
Low    A          0.888889
       B          0.361111
Open   B          0.000000
       C          1.000000
```

Is there a way to sort the above within each group (Low,Open)?

If I call `.sort_values()` it sorts the entire series, which is not what I want. I want to preserve the grouping of it.

I also tried looping over each group and sort and reassign BUT it was incorrect as the values were sorted by the labels (ABC) were not, so totally mixed up.

Thanks

Comment: could you share the code to generate the data

Comment: There are only 2 values? `Low` and `Open` ?

Comment: the original function to create the data is like 200 lines long. the above code is like a small snippet. I remember there is a method call that outputs the code so when its ran, it produces the same dataframe...but forgot what it was called. Great way to send you code to others... do you guys know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use if there is no levels names first [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and then [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) for correct order of sorting also with indices:

```
s = (s.rename_axis(['id1','id2'])
      .groupby('id1', group_keys=False, sort=False)
      .apply(pd.Series.sort_values)))
print (s)
id1   id2
Low   B      0.361111
      A      0.888889
Open  B      0.000000
      C      1.000000
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: seems like you use the same logic as mine :-) nice one ~

Comment: @BEN_YO - yes, it is interesting `transform` not change indices.

Comment: Kind of wired , seems like transform is doing the array changing, not pandas object

Comment: @BEN_YO - ya, it has sense